# PhotoKit: Crash [assetsd was interrupted or died] when using requestImageForAsset to fetch asset with PHImageManagerMaximumSize

Tags: ios, crash, photokit

I am trying to display Image using UIPageViewController, using the sample code from apple and replacing it with the new photo Kit: PHAsset [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135](http://ImagePicker) 
When i swiping the photo with PHImageManagerMaximumSize, i found that after 50 photos, the app will crash showing "assetsd interrupted or died". But if i request a smaller target size(same size as screen), the crash is becoming unlikely. I am wondering if it is a memory leak somewhere in my app or there is something wrong in the rendering system ? Seems the compression and uncompression are using a lot of pages.  Could anyone help me to have a look?

```
- (void)displayImage:(PHAsset*)asset
{
 [self.imageView removeFromSuperView]
 self.imageView = nil;
 [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:result];
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        // self is a scrollView    
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];
    }];
}
```

------ log in console ----------

2015-02-27 22:35:20.613 XXX [2831:145514] ImageViewController, -[ImageViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
2015-02-27 22:35:22.111 XXX [2831:145558] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

------- crash logs ---------

Free pages:                              1361
Active pages:                            26954
Inactive pages:                          13499
Speculative pages:                       40
Throttled pages:                         0
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             59258
File-backed pages:                       11321
Anonymous pages:                         29172
Compressions:                            6474001
Decompressions:                          704086
Compressor Size:                         151510
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        212409
Page Size:                               16384
Largest process:   iGather

Processes
     Name       |                            |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

assistant_servic <97db64323f2e364ea0af497680126850>         0.485        1451                0           -          4111   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
   medialibraryd <6a42c5e99f153b4baa0992e9902bee82>         0.296        1037                0           -          2072   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
WirelessRadioMan          0.077         285                0           -           890   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
            awdd <58036e1703903ee798a8803de204c300>         0.070         402                0           -          1043   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
         assetsd <276c271c5b073f58bf87c49abf22b264>         0.188         679                0           -          1907   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
            seld <18863ab32c7634d5b7f200821acffd06>         0.030         193                0           -           696   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
           passd <56971afa88b53f05a37688cad47b4160>         0.243         630                0           -          2384   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
            nfcd <59e46913bec838d989d5bed82cb05791>         0.023         184                0           -           624   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
   biometrickitd <71607be9393c366eb1bbe281256fde77>         0.141         273                0           -           841   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
     debugserver          0.306         207                0           -           629   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
      MobileMail <4b48abd990e93dbea47db1cbf328da9e>         0.957        1496                0           -          4063   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (resume) (continuous)
             lsd          1.213         364                0           -          1032   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
            tccd          0.132         238                0           -           593   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
             kbd <8c8bded31cf73db2b44aa996c0e90921>         0.116         344                0           -          1447   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
         iGather          3.610       23061                0           -         21099   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (frontmost) (resume)
...

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYourApp/MemoryManagementforYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1) to confirm this, but I've found that even with ARC you have to be conservative with memory usage when processing a batch of photos.

Like you I wanted to provide the user with the highest possible quality image so they can zoom in and examine the photo in detail. I display N photos in a grid. I found that even when getting rid of all references to those assets, they're not freed before the next set of N is loaded. I just had to cut my memory usage in half so that brief transition where N * 2 are in memory didn't crash my app.

Of course, if your memory usage is increasingly monotonically then you probably do have surviving references to those images somewhere in your code. Again, Instruments.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i think i have found the reason. It is because the view controller the PageViewController created is no released. Yes, like you said, Instruments.